# How to check value is already there in an existing JSON file Node JS

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a json file with addresses in backend side.. From client side I'm getting an address of user as a post method through API.
I want to check whether the address entered by user is already exist in JSON file or not. In json file address are already as lowercase formate.
I'm tottally new to Node and JS. This is what I tried. and I'm getting error "message": "address.equals is not a function"

```
const addressesAsJson = require('../data/addresslist.json')

 function addressCheck (
  address /* : string | void */
) /* :Promise<Object[]> */ {

  var convertAdLowerCase = address.toLowerCase()

  return Promise.resolve()
    .then(() => {
      console.log(address)
      return addressesAsJson.filter((address) => address.equals(convertAdLowerCase))

      console.log(address.equals(convertAdLowerCase))
    })


}
```

My JSON format look like this

```
{"address":"new south park , western sydney , australia 2345","display":"New South Park , WESTERN SYDNEY , AUSTRALIA 2345"}
```

Comment: `This is what I tried` - what happened when you tried this?

Comment: `address.equals` is not a function? Yes, it would probably do that. JavaScript is not Java. Java tests string equality using `.equals`. JavaScript uses `===` or `==`. (Also, you can't log anything after `return`. Or do anything else after `return`. So your second `console.log` will not do anything, ever.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use equal operator

```
address === convertAdLowerCase
```

and remove the console log which is after the return since it is unreachable code.

Perfect code would be

```
 return Promise.resolve()
    .then(() => {
      console.log(address);
      const allMatches = addressesAsJson.filter((record) => record.address === convertAdLowerCase));
      console.log(allMatches);
      return allMatches.length > 0;
 });
```

Comment: Whatever the value I'm adding ,it's getting true

Comment: It's not checking the address from JSON file. That's what is getting true. It's checking the value with return value and convertAdLowerCase

Comment: addressesAsJson.filter((address) => address === convertAdLowerCase)).length > 0

Comment: filter returns an empty array, but it's always true. So you should check the length of it. Btw is your JSON file an array or just a JSON object. If it's a JSON object, you can't use filter

Comment: I want to compare the address value of json with convertAdLowerCase. In here it's comparing post return value 'address' with convertAdLowerCase. Then it always true. This is not what I need

Comment: How can I return the result in console .log now? I want to check. Why does it check the length?

Comment: Because filter returns an array with all the matching records.
edited the answer, check now.

Answer (score 0):

Plz refer [link](http://www.mattzeunert.com/2016/01/28/javascript-deep-equal.html)

```
var a = {"address":"new south park , western sydney , australia 2345","display":"New South Park , WESTERN SYDNEY , AUSTRALIA 2345"};
var b = {"address":"New south Park , western sydney , australia 2345","display":"New South Park , WESTERN SYDNEY , AUSTRALIA 2345"}
function jsonEqual(a,b) {
    return JSON.stringify(a).toLowerCase() === JSON.stringify(b).toLowerCase();
}
console.log(jsonEqual(a, b))
```